# Button not functioning inside case statement

Tags: arduino

I have written a sketch that works fine, however I cannot get a 2nd button (to use as 'select') to work within the case statement.

I have tried using an if/else statement and in the serial monitor it doesnt read the button, but the button does work if outside the case statement.

```cpp
#include <TM1637Display.h>


//*************************** GLOBALS ********************

// TM1637 Module connection pins (Digital Pins)
#define CLK 9
#define DIO 8
TM1637Display display(CLK, DIO);


// Buttons
const int startPin = 5;
int startState = 0;
int startpressed = 0;
const int selectPin = 6;
int selectState = 0;
int selectpressed = 0;

const uint8_t SEG_BLANK[] = {
  SEG_G,                                   //  -
  SEG_G,                                   //  -
  SEG_G,                                   //  -
  SEG_G                                    //  -
};
const uint8_t SEG_DONE[] = {
  SEG_B | SEG_C | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_G,           // d
  SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_C | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_F,   // O
  SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_C | SEG_E | SEG_F,           // N
  SEG_A | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_G            // E
};
const uint8_t SEG_P1[] = {
  SEG_G,                                           // -
  SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_G,           // P
  SEG_B | SEG_C,                                   // 1
  SEG_G                                            // -
};

const uint8_t SEG_P2[] = {
  SEG_G,                                           // -
  SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_G,           // P
  SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_G,           // 2
  SEG_G                                            // -
};

const uint8_t SEG_P3[] = {
  SEG_G,                                           // -
  SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_G,           // P
  SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_C | SEG_D | SEG_G,           // 3
  SEG_G                                            // -
};

const uint8_t SEG_P4[] = {
  SEG_G,                                           // -
  SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_G,           // P
  SEG_B | SEG_C | SEG_F | SEG_G,                   // 4
  SEG_G                                            // -
};

const uint8_t SEG_F1[] = {
  SEG_G,                                           // -
  SEG_A | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_G,                   // F
  SEG_B | SEG_C,                                   // 1
  SEG_G                                            // -
};

const uint8_t SEG_F2[] = {
  SEG_G,                                           // -
  SEG_A | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_G,                   // F
  SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_G,           // 2
  SEG_G                                            // -
};

// time calc
#define numberOfSeconds(_time_) ((_time_ / 1000) % 60)
#define numberOfMinutes(_time_) ((_time_ / 1000) / 60)

// Setup program timers
unsigned long timeLimit = 1000;  // 1000*60*20 = 20

// Setup relays
int RelayExternal = 12;
//int RelayDark = ;
//int RelayLight = ;
//int RelayAmber = ;
//int RelayNIR = ;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(selectPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(startPin, INPUT);
  pinMode (RelayExternal, OUTPUT);
  //  pinMode (RelayDark, OUTPUT);
  //  pinMode (RelayLight, OUTPUT);
  //  pinMode (RelayAmber, OUTPUT);
  //  pinMode (RelayNI, OUTPUT);
  delay(50);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //display setup
  display.setBrightness(2);    // LED 0~6
  //display.setBrightness(0x0c);
  display.showNumberDecEx(0, 0x40, true);    //64
}

//SETUP FUNCTIONS

void DashedLine()
{
  Serial.println("----------------");
}

void External() {
  digitalWrite(RelayExternal, HIGH);
}

//SETUP TIMER
void Timer() {
  for (long i = timeLimit; i > 0; i = i - 1000) // data type
  { // To display the countdown in mm:ss format, separate the parts
    int seconds = numberOfSeconds(i);
    int minutes = numberOfMinutes(i);
    Serial.println(i);
    display.showNumberDecEx(seconds, 0, true, 2, 2) ; // This displays the seconds in the last two places
    display.showNumberDecEx(minutes, (0x80 >> 1), true, 2, 0) ;  // Display the minutes in the first two places, with colon
    delay(1000);
  }
  display.setSegments(SEG_DONE); // Display finished
}



//LOOP
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(RelayExternal, HIGH);

  // Check the state of Select Button
  if (digitalRead(selectPin) == HIGH)
  {
    if (selectpressed == 0)
    {
      selectpressed = 1;
      Serial.println("Select pressed");
      switch (selectState)
      {

        case 0: // Start case - - - -
          display.setSegments(SEG_BLANK);
          delay (200);
          display.setSegments(SEG_P1);
          delay (200);
          display.setSegments(SEG_P2);
          delay (200);
          display.setSegments(SEG_P3);
          delay (200);
          display.setSegments(SEG_P4);
          delay (200);
          display.setSegments(SEG_F1);
          delay (200);
          display.setSegments(SEG_F2);
          delay (200);
          display.setSegments(SEG_BLANK);

          Serial.println ("START PROGRAM (- - - -)");
          delay(5); //Debounce
          selectState++;
          break;

        case 1: // Programme 1 P1 14

          // Display pre-defined segment pattern
          display.setSegments(SEG_P1);
          Serial.println ("Program 1 : 14 minutes");

      // Check the state of Start Button
      if (digitalRead(startPin) == HIGH)
        {
          Serial.println("start case");
          if (startpressed == 0)
          {
            startpressed = 1;
            Serial.println("Start pressed");
            switch (startState)
              {
              case 0: // Start case - - - -
              // Button two pressed
              Serial.println("BUTTON 2 PRESSED");
              delay(5); //Debounce
              startState++;
              break;
              }
          }
        }
          else 
        {
          startpressed = 0;
        }     

          delay(5); //Debounce
          selectState++;
          break;

        case 2:
          // Display pre-defined segment pattern
          display.setSegments(SEG_P2);
          Serial.println ("Program 2 : 14 minutes");
          Serial.println("P2 TIMER RUNNING");
          selectState++;
          break;

        case 3:
          // Display pre-defined segment pattern
          display.setSegments(SEG_P3);
          Serial.println ("Program 3 : 14 minutes");
          Serial.println("P3 TIMER RUNNING");
          selectState++;
          break;


        case 4:
          // Display pre-defined segment pattern
          display.setSegments(SEG_P4);
          Serial.println ("Program 4 : 14 minutes");
          Serial.println("P4 TIMER RUNNING");
          selectState++;
          break;


        case 5:
          // Display pre-defined segment pattern
          display.setSegments(SEG_F1);
          Serial.println ("Program 5 : 14 minutes");
          Serial.println("P5 TIMER RUNNING");
          selectState = 1;
          break;

      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    selectpressed = 0;
  }


}












// If button B pressed then set and start timer, if not then continue code.
//      Serial.println("Program 1 : START");  // Serial update
// Turn on relay
//     digitalWrite (RelayExternal, LOW);
//     Serial.println("Relay External : ON");  // Serial update
//     DashedLine();

// Set timer duration
//     timeLimit = 11000;  // 1000*60*20 = 20
// Start timer function
//     Timer();


//      DashedLine();
//      Serial.println("Program 1 : DONE");  // Serial update
// Turn off relay
//      digitalWrite (RelayExternal, HIGH);
//      Serial.println("Relay External : OFF");  // Serial update
//     DashedLine();
```

What I am trying to achieve is the 1st button selects the 'Program' such as P1, P2 etc.. then to execute that program the 2nd button is pressed which runs the timer.

Any idea's what I am doing wrong?

Oh and I've removed the actual code I used since it didn't work, I'm assuming it's something to do with the case loop?

Comment: Where is selectState ever changed?

Comment: It is incremented at the end of each case.  "selectState++;" Until the last case (5) where I choose to set it to 1 so it skips the first case scenario.